# Fancybox images and youtube in 1 gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, fancybox-2

Hello StackOverflowers,

I am having a problem with fancybox, I want to have images and 2 youtube video's in 1 gallery.

It does load and show my images, but it does not putt my videos in the gallery. It is hard to explain [so I will link the page where i have this problem here](http://www.chrisholsteindesign.com/3dsmax.html)

I load my scripts as following:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style/jquery.fancybox.css" media="screen" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.fancybox-media.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style/3dsmax.css" />
```

I am using some helpers:

```
$('a.fancybox').fancybox({
        prevEffect : 'none',
        nextEffect : 'none',

        closeBtn  : true,
        arrows    : true,
        nextClick : true,


        helpers : {
            thumbs : {
                width  : 50,
                height : 50
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

according to fancybox's doc:

> You can specify type directly by adding classname (fancybox.image, fancybox.iframe, etc)

you should also use the embed url of the video, your `<a>` tags should now look like this :

```
<a class="fancybox hidden fancybox.iframe" data-fancybox-group="gallery4" href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/8so-fsGxXZ8"><img src="./Chris Holstein's Portfolio_files/cdpreview.jpg"></a>
<a class="fancybox hidden fancybox.iframe" data-fancybox-group="gallery4" href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/USNfjkTny78"><img src="./Chris Holstein's Portfolio_files/doospreview.jpg"></a>
```

BTW you should avoid file names with spaces, sometimes it leads to weird behaviour...

Comment: did you put the embed url ?

Comment: still doesn't work, If I check the demo it uses the same URL notation as I am using.

Comment: ok I downloaded the page you provided and tested on my own computer, this time it works, you just need to combine both answers :-) I edited my answer...